# Align sentences of a text file to left and right in PHP

Tags: php

```
    $result = "";

    while (some condition)
{
    $result = file_get_contents("filename.txt");
    $result = "$result\n" . $result;
    file_put_contents("filename.txt", $result);
}

    echo nl2br ($result);
```

I want to echo the first line as left aligned and second line as right aligned and so on on a web page. Is there any way to achieve this?

Comment: If the result is to be displayed on a website you could use paragraphs and adjust them with CSS. if not, why dont you mention it in your question?

Comment: How can you use CSS and HTML for every line of the text file@evayly

Answer (score 0):

```
$aLines = readfile(<file>);


for( $i = 0; $i < count( $aLines ); $i++ ) {
    $align = ($i%2)?"left":"right";
    echo "<div style='text-align: {$align}'>{$aLines[$i]}</div>";
}
```

Or if you meant to align inside the file itself:

```
$aLines = readfile(<source_file>);
$iLineWidth = 100;    

$aLinesNew = [];
for( $i = 0; $i < count( $aLines ); $i++ ) {
    $sLine = ($i%2)?$aLines[$i]:str_pad( $aLines[$i], $iLineWidth, " ", STR_PAD_LEFT);
    $sLine = trim($sLine);
    array_push( $aLinesNew, $sLine );
}
file_put_contents( <destination_file>, implode( "\n", $aLinesNew ) );
```

Comment: Thank you for answering but I want to read the variable $result. Your code suggest to read the file filename.txt @Pilan

Answer (score 0):

First you can split the text into an array buy using  `implode` and use CSS to align them:

```
$result = "";

while (some condition){
  $result = file_get_contents("filename.txt");
  $result = "$result\n" . $result;
  file_put_contents("filename.txt", $result);
}

$lines = implode('\n',$result);

echo "<div class='lines'>";
foreach($lines as $line){
  echo $line;
}
echo "</div>";

// CSS:
echo '.lines > div:nth(even){ text-align:right; }';
```

Comment: Your code seems to be right. But, I don't know why it's not working @user3284463